# Automatically detecting cyclic dependencies with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, dependencies, cycle

I want to automatically fail a build when a cyclic dependency is detected (to avoid build loops in Jenkins, among other things). The problem is the detection.

Maven 3 itself detects cyclic dependencies when the cyclic dependency is within the reactor (ie. executed from the same top-level module). Otherwise it is useless in that regard.

There is the [extra maven enforcer rule](http://mojo.codehaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/) [banCircularDependencies](http://mojo.codehaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/banCircularDependencies.html). However, it seems to be limited to what "mvn dependency:tree" does, ie. it [fails to recognize](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MENFORCER-215) transitive test scope dependencies.

```
scope
  The scope to filter by when resolving the dependency tree, or null to
  include dependencies from all scopes. Note that this feature does not
  currently work due to MNG-3236.
```

Is there any other solution to that problem?

Answer (score 0):

[One way](http://blog.mafr.de/2010/10/02/java-finding-package-cycles/) is to set up a unit test using the [JDepend](http://www.clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html) API and assertions corresponding to what you want.

```
JDepend jdepend = new JDepend();
jdepend.addDirectory("target/classes");
jdepend.analyze();
// add assertion here;
```